# how to use the plantUML preview in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, plantuml

I am trying to use plantuml add-ons on VSCode: there are several but none of them is working.
In this eample I am using the plantUML add-on.

[image: the extension I am using]

[image: My VSCode]

As you can see on the second image the preview is blank.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 62):

I had the same issue. My preview started working right after I installed the [Java Runtime Environment (JRE)](https://java.com/en/download/).

Comment: Thank you Bruno, I had same issue and installing JRE and reopening vs-code after worked.

Comment: For Ubuntu users: `sudo apt install default-jre`

Answer (score 6):

the solution is:

You can open the diagram by hitting ALT + D to preview the PlantUML diagram on Windows and Option key + D on Mac.

Answer (score 5):

On windows, you can now use chocolatey:

> choco install plantuml

You then have to restart VsCode for the previewer to properly work.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is right, however there is another issue too. I am going to post here the other issue for anyone wandering, because that issue is not on stackoverflow.

If you find the error:

- "No valid diagram found here!"

Than here are the answers:

- [Previews shows "No valid diagram found here!" all the time](https://github.com/qjebbs/vscode-plantuml/issues/140)
- [No valid diagram found here](https://github.com/qjebbs/vscode-plantuml/issues/115)

In short:

- As mentioned [here](https://github.com/qjebbs/vscode-plantuml/issues/115#issuecomment-384874449), try to put the cursor somewhere between @startuml and @enduml, and then press ALT + D to open the preview. If the cursor is outside of the @startuml @enduml block, the "No valid diagrams found here!" error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download [Java Runtime](https://java.com/en/download/) . Click "Instructions"
2. Install graphviz

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install graphviz
```

3. Enjoy

Comment: this seems like an incomplete answer?

Answer (score 1):

My local server doesn't want to render. I changed server to plantuml.com
See details here: https://skalolaskovy.ru/analytics/65-system-analytics/603-vs-code-does-not-generate-diagram (russian lang.)

Comment: Thank you! My local JRE installation was blocked and this way I was able to generate previews :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use plantUML on VSCode with WSL remote, try this :

```
sudo apt install plantuml
```

Comment: An alright alternative, but OP is asking about the VS Code extension.

Comment: this answer solved the problem in a round-about way by installing java if it isn't already installed. The accepted answer is a more direct solution. The VSCode extension comes bundled with the `plantuml.jar` so it isn't necessary to install it at a system level